# Is it possible to use the Parrinello-Rahman barostat for NPT simulations in CP2K?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, cp2k

It is possible to use different types of thermostats in CP2K by specifying them in the corresponding section of the input as mentioned [here](https://manual.cp2k.org/cp2k-7_1-branch/CP2K_INPUT/MOTION/MD/THERMOSTAT.html#TYPE). But there is no mention of specifying the barostat type in the [manual](https://manual.cp2k.org/cp2k-7_1-branch/CP2K_INPUT/MOTION/MD/BAROSTAT.html). And I couldn't find any mention of the type of barostat being used in CP2K for NPT simulations. So is it possible to use the Parrinello-Rahman barostat for NPT simulations in CP2K?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The barostat used by CP2K is the one developped by Glenn J. Martyna et al. [J. Chem. Phys. 101, 4177 (1994)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.467468).

The Parrinello-Rahman barostat is not implemented in CP2K.